# Rendering destructed data when data could hold different things

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

Assume I have the following code

```
const [loaded,setLoaded]=useState(false);
const[data,SetData]=useState();
useEffect(() => {
    let GetData= async(){ await axios.get("").data;
    SetData(data);
    setLoaded(true);}

    GetData();

}, [])
return(<>
    <DefaultComponent></DefaultComponent>
    {loaded && data.status=="success"?
    <OtherComps name={data.user.name} reference={data.user.reference} username={data.user.creds.username} profilePic={data.user.profile.card.picture} ></OtherComps>
    :
    <ErrorComp></ErrorComp>
}
</>)
```

`<DefaultComponent>` will always be rendered regardless of loaded or `data.status` which holds success if `statusCode=200`. Now the issue is all that property referencing in render. `data.user` wouldn't exist if `status != "success"`. for that reason I cant have a `const {user}=data` and `const {profile}=data.user` I could do the following however

```
if(loaded==false)
{
    return(<div> 
        <DefaultComponent></DefaultComponent>
        <div>loading</div>
        </div>)
}
if(data.status!="success")
{
    return(
        <>
            <DefaultComponent></DefaultComponent>
            <ErrorComp></ErrorComp>
        </>
    )
}
const{user}=data;
    const{profile}=data.user;
    return(<>
        <DefaultComponent></DefaultComponent>
        <OtherComps name={user.name} 
reference={duser.reference} username={user.creds.username}
 profilePic={profile.card.picture}></OtherComps>
    
    </>)
```

the issue with this is i have the  3 many times and its not readable. Plus in real browser it makes a little blinking affect because of all the different renderings. it will be a bigger issue if  happens to be a more complex component with a lot of data and images.
How do you guys get around this? am i supposed to use method 2 because the property references is more readable or method 1 because its better put together?

Answer (score 0):

I think first approach is better than second one because in second one, your `DefaultComponent` will unmount and mount again multiple times but in first approach, it will only mount one time.

I will also recommend to change your code structure in first approach like below:-

```
  return (
    <>
      <DefaultComponent />
      {loaded ? (
        data.status === 'success' ? (
          <OtherComps
            name={data.user.name}
            reference={data.user.reference}
            username={data.user.creds.username}
            profilePic={data.user.profile.card.picture}
          />
        ) : (
          <ErrorComp />
        )
      ) : (
        <div>
          <div>loading</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```